# How to coordinate transform this Lagrangian?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

Suppose we have a Lagrangian which has general coordinates $\vec{r}, \vec{k}$:

$$
L = -\dot{\vec{k}}\cdot(\vec{r}-\vec{a})+\frac{1}{2}\vec{b}\times\dot{\vec{r}}\cdot\vec{r}
$$

where $\vec{b}$ is constant vector and $\vec{a}=\vec{a}(\vec{k})$.

Let's make a coordinate change:
$$
\vec{q}=\vec{r}-\vec{a} \\
\vec{p}=\vec{k}-\frac{1}{2}\vec{b}\times\vec{r}
$$

**Question is, what is the transformed Lagrangian(can be different by a total time derivative)?**

According to my resource, the transformed one looks like:

$$
L=(\vec{p}-\frac{1}{2}\vec{b}\times\vec{a})\cdot\dot{\vec{q}}-\frac{1}{2}\vec{b}\times\vec{a}\cdot p_i\partial_i\vec{a}
$$

However, according to my calculation, which is simply replace the originals by the new ones:

$$
L = (\vec{p}-\frac{1}{2}\vec{b}\times\vec{a})\cdot\dot{\vec{q}}-\frac{1}{2}\vec{b}\times\vec{a}\cdot \dot{\vec{a}}
$$

The last step is to calculate $\dot{\vec{a}}$, which I think is $\dot{\vec{a}}=(\dot{p_i}+\frac{1}{2}(\vec{b}\times\dot{\vec{r}})_i)\partial_i\vec{a}$, after this I don't know how to proceed, it seems hard to get rid of $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{k}$.

Maybe I am facing a very naive mistake, can someone help me to point it out?

**Bonus question** if you have time (not essential to my concern here, I will accept the answer even if the bonus is not answered), can you make a coordinate change such that:

$$
L=\vec{P}\cdot \dot{\vec{Q}}
$$